# compass watch command is erroring out when trying to access compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.16/stylesheets/.listen_test

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I believe this happened after upgrading to Ruby 2.0.0 and then I resintalled my gems needed for compass watch. I also installed Ruby 1.9.1 and installed the gems for compass watch and got the same error. I tried to change the permissions on the file .listen_test, but it doesn't exist.

Here's the --trace:

```
compass watch --trace

>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.

error sites/all/themes/dr/compass/sass/blog-ie.sass (Line 919 of sites/all/themes/dr/compass/sass/blog.sass: Invalid flag "!important".)

identical sites/all/themes/dr/compass/css/blog-ie.css 

error sites/all/themes/dr/compass/sass/blog.sass (Line 919: Invalid flag "!important".)

identical sites/all/themes/dr/compass/css/blog.css 

Errno::EACCES on line ["1140"] of /Users/ejohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb: Permission denied -      /Users/ejohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.16/stylesheets/.listen_test

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1140:in `open'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1140:in `rescue in block in touch'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1136:in `block in touch'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1134:in `each'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1134:in `touch'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:221:in `works?'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:182:in `block in usable_and_works?'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:182:in `each'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:182:in `all?'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:182:in `usable_and_works?'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:49:in `block in select_and_initialize'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:47:in `each'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:47:in `select_and_initialize'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/listener.rb:272:in `initialize_adapter'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/listener.rb:264:in `setup'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/listener.rb:64:in `start!'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.17/lib/compass/watcher/project_watcher.rb:31:in `watch!'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.17/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:48:in `perform'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.17/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.17/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.17/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.17/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.17/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.17/bin/compass:44:in `call'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.17/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/compass:23:in `load'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'

/Users/ejohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Here are my local gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0)
breakpoint (2.3.1)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
chunky_png (1.2.9)
compass (1.0.0.alpha.17, 0.12.2)
compass-core (1.0.0.alpha.16)
compass-import-once (1.0.1)
compass-rgbapng (0.2.1)
executable-hooks (1.2.6)
ffi (1.9.3)
fssm (0.2.10)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
listen (1.1.6)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.8.2)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
rb-inotify (0.9.3)
rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
rdoc (3.9.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sass (3.3.0.rc.2, 3.2.12)
susy (1.0.9)
```

EDIT
I got compass watch working by installing an older version of compass (0.12.2)

Comment: I'm trying to use compass animate, which is only for 0.13, so downgrading is not really an option, the good thing is that "compass compile" is still working, only "watch" isn't

Comment: Ah, good to know. I'll try "compass compile" and see if that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it to work with:

```
sudo compass watch
```

I'm not sure why now I need the sudo.

Comment: This works for me too. Sweet! But yeah, weird that sudo is needed now.

Answer (score 1):

You have the older version of one of the gems.  I would guess it is 'listen'

Someone opened an issue with the same problem.

https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1497

Edit:  Actually this might be a compass issue.  Made some local changes and got beyond the error.  Pull request posted pending review.  I don't do ruby, but hopefully it's a start to get it resolved.  https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/pull/1522

Comment: You can get past the error until this is resolved with sudo as mentioned above or adding --poll to your watch options.