# import not found or unreadable: breakpoint

Tags: sass, susy-compass, breakpoint-sass

Just installed breakpoint and tried using on an existing blog project (html/css/js/php). Currently using Sass with Susy for basic grid stuff but wanted to give Breakpoint a try on this project as I recently became aware of it's ease and flexible use.

After install was successful added the following to my project:

`require 'breakpoint'` to config.rb file

`@import "breakpoint"`  to _base file in sass.

Upon refresh was given this error message in the browser:

`Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.\A Load paths:\A /Users/pbj/Desktop/code/the-start/themes/thestart/sass\A /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.3/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets\A /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.3/frameworks/compass/stylesheets\A /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass\A Compass::SpriteImporter\A on line 6 of /Users/pbj/Desktop/code/the-start/themes/thestart/sass/_base.scss\A from line 5 of /Users/pbj/Desktop/code/the-start/themes/thestart/sass/screen.scss\A \A 1: /Users/pbj/Desktop/code/the-start/themes/thestart/sass/screen.scss"`

Also had this error in the command line:

`Errno::EACCES on line ["1143"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.17/stylesheets/.listen_test
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace`

Upon running a full backtrace I was given this in the command line:

`` Errno::EACCES on line ["1143"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.17/stylesheets/.listen_test
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1143:in open'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1143:inrescue in block in touch'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1139:in block in touch'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1137:ineach'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1137:in touch'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:221:inworks?'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:182:in block in usable_and_works?'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:182:ineach'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:182:in all?'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:182:inusable_and_works?'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:49:in block in select_and_initialize'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:47:ineach'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:47:in select_and_initialize'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/listener.rb:272:ininitialize_adapter'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/listener.rb:264:in setup'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.1.6/lib/listen/listener.rb:64:instart!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.18/lib/compass/watcher/project_watcher.rb:31:in watch!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.18/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:48:inperform'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.18/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in execute'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.18/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:inexecute'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.18/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in perform!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.18/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:inrun!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.18/bin/compass:30:in block in <top (required)>'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.18/bin/compass:44:incall'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.18/bin/compass:44:in <top (required)>'
  /usr/bin/compass:23:inload'
  /usr/bin/compass:23:in `' ``

When I installed breakpoint it also installed:

- sass-3.3.0.rc.6
- compass-1.0.0.alpha.18
- breakpoint-2.4.1

When I checked current version of sass it was sass-3.3.0.rc.6.

Not sure exactly whats happening. I did read similar issues where the resolution was to call `compass watch`  on the parent directory of the config.rb file, or something to that extent. Still ended up with same error.

EDIT: When commenting out breakpoint to try and move forward without using (momentarily) this error is throw in the browser:

`"Syntax error: Undefined variable: \"$experimental-support-for-mozilla\".\A on line 25 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass/susy/_support.scss\A from line 5 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass/_susy.scss\A from line 5 of /Users/pbj/Desktop/code/the-start/themes/thestart/sass/_base.scss\A from line 5 of /Users/pbj/Desktop/code/the-start/themes/thestart/sass/screen.scss"`

And this error in the command line: 
`Errno::EACCES on line ["1143"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.17/stylesheets/.listen_test`

Figured this is because its trying to use v3.3?

Any one have some advice on how to resolve the issue?

Currently running 15" MBPr OSX v.10.9.2 (Mavericks)

Comment: Not sure on the Breakpoint problems, but it looks like you need a newer version of Susy.  The `$experimental-support-for-mozilla` variable comes from Compass versions older than 1.0.

Comment: @cimmanon Hmmm. Just tried that and got even more errors... Separate, Susy based errors.

Comment: Then go ahead and stick to the older version (since there may have been API changes since the version you've been using), and set that variable to true somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, you either need to update everything to use Sass 3.3 (the Susy 2.0 pre-release), or you need to use an older version of Breakpoint. If you want to upgrade Susy, try changing your import from "susy" to "susyone" so you don't get any syntax errors. That might take care of the problems you were seeing.

Comment: @EricSuzanneMeyer So it looks like that fixed most of the errors & lets me to reload. 

Although, I'm still running into an error when trying to run 'compass watch'. It throws an error and aborts the watch command all together. 

Here's the error, looks to be the same as above about the .listen_test



    Errno::EACCES on line ["1143"] of    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.17/stylesheets/.listen_test
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

Comment: That looks like a [known bug in Compass](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1497). I've seen a lot of people running into it recently. Hopefully there will be a patch soon.

Comment: @EricSuzanneMeyer The only thing I've found to fix the 'compass watch' command from throwing an error is running 'sudo compass watch'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your woes is [Bundler](http://bundler.io/)! Bundler will lock your project into specific gems and ensure they're available for use. If you are using Susy 1.x and want to use Breakpoint, your Gemfile should look like the following:

`source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'sass', '~>3.2.0'
gem 'compass', '~>0.12.0'
gem 'susy', '~>1.0.0'
gem 'breakpoint', '~>2.0.0'`

If, however, you would like to use the latest and greatest, your Gemfile should look like the following:

`source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'sass', '~>3.3.0.rc.3'
gem 'compass', '~>1.0.0.alpha.18'
gem 'susy', '~>2.0.0.rc.2'
gem 'breakpoint', '~>2.4.0'`

Remember to `bundle install` and run your Compass compiling through `bundle exec` (`bundle exec compass watch`)

Comment: and if I have no gemfile? This isn't a rails app, just some static files and php.

Comment: If you have no Gemfile, make one. Bundler should be used with any project that touches Ruby, not just Rails apps. Sass and Compass are Ruby projects, so you should be running them with Bundler.

Comment: Thanks for the info. All worked well creating and running bundler with the gemfile. 

Still ran into an issue where I couldn't get the watch command to run. Running <code>compass watch </code> or <code>bundle exec compass watch</code> resulted in the same error as above (references the listen_test. 

I did some googling and [found a few folks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621062/compass-watch-command-is-erroring-out-when-trying-to-access-compass-core-1-0-0-a) using <code>sudo compass watch</code> to watch their sass files and that seems to work. Not sure why though exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when install breakpoint via npm, and I fix it by **npm install breakpoint-sass**, then I import it in my **app.scss** like this
**@import '~/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint';**

use this code for responsive layout :

.class-name {

```
    **@include breakpoint(max-width 800px) {
     ...
    }**
```

}